# A right elliptical cone is 4m high and has an elliptical base with half axes lengths of 1m and 2m. Find its volume.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, volume

A right elliptical cone is $4$m high and has an elliptical base with half axes lengths of $1$m and $2$m. Find its volume. [The area of an ellipse with half axes lengths $a$ and $b$ is $πab$.]

I know that $V = \int A(x) \ dx$. I've usually used this in the context of solids of revolution using circles, but I have never encountered a problem like this. I have also sketched an image of an upside-down cone, with the x-axis going from the apex of the cone to the base, such that the base is located at $x = 4$. Therefore, the x-axis is representing height.

However, I am unsure of how to proceed from here. I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to help me with this problem.

Comment: This comment has more to do with synthetic geometry than calculus, but Cavalieri's principle ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri's_principle#Cones_and_pyramids) has something interesting to say about problems like this: "The fact that the volume of any pyramid, regardless of the shape of the base, whether circular as in the case of a cone, or square as in the case of the Egyptian pyramids, or any other shape, is (1/3) × base × height, can be established by Cavalieri's principle". If you are looking to find a solution via calculus, this may not help you though - just food for thought

Comment: @joeb Thanks for the response. Could you please show me how I may use this to solve this problem?

Comment: The best way for me to answer is to draw the "cone". I see if I can figure out a way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

In the figure above, $a = 1$ and $b=2$. I'll call the figure a cone even though its base is not circular.

Sit the cone in question pointing upward with its elliptical base on the plane $xy$-plane and its apex sitting on the $z$-axis four units above the origin.

A plane parallel to the $xy$-plane at a height $0 \leqslant h \leqslant 4$ units above the origin will intersect the cone at an ellipse $E(h)$ with major half-axis $b(h)$ and minor half-axis $a(h)$ - I haven't actually drawn $E(h)$ but I did draw its half-axes. For instance, $E(0)$ is the base of the cone with $a(0) = 1$ and $b(0) = 2$.

To find $a(h),b(h)$ in terms of $a,b$, use similar triangles: $$\frac{a(h)}{4-h} = \frac{a}{4} = \frac{1}{4} \Longrightarrow a(h) = \frac{1}{4}(4-h)$$ $$\frac{b(h)}{4-h} = \frac{b}{4} = \frac{2}{4} \Longrightarrow b(h) = \frac{1}{2}(4-h).$$
Thus, $$A(h) := \mathsf{area}(E(h)) = a(h)b(h)\pi = \frac{\pi}{8}(4-h)^2.$$

To find the area of the cone, integrate:
$$ \int_0^4 A(h) dh = \frac{\pi}{8} \int_0^4 (4-h)^2 dh $$ $$= -\frac{\pi}{8} \int_4^0 t^2 dt = \frac{\pi}{8}\int_0^4 t^2 dt = \frac{\pi}{8}\left( \frac{(4)^3}{3} - \frac{(0)^3}{3} \right) = \frac{8\pi}{3}. $$
Note that I used the substitution $t = 4-h$ to solve the integral. Note also that $$\frac{8 \pi}{3} = (1/3)(2\pi)(4) = (1/3)(\mathrm{area \,\, of \,\, base})(\mathrm{height}).$$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a solution; I greatly appreciate it. :) I think I understood most of what I have read so far, until I reached the similar triangles concept. I understand what similar triangles are, but how did you use them in these calculations? For instance, where did $\frac{a(h)}{4-h}$ come from? How was the concept of similar triangles used to find these calculations? I would greatly appreciate it if you could please elaborate on this part of your answer. I have seen similar triangles used before, but I have always been confused by how they were used, such as here.

Comment: The triangle in the figure that has base $a$ and is the same height of the cone (which is $4$) is similar to the smaller triangle in the figure that has base $a(h)$ and height $4-h$. The reason the height of the smaller triangle is $4-h$ is because you subtract from the height of the cone $4$ the height $h$ the ellipse $E(h)$ is already lifted above the origin

Comment: Ok, thank you; that all makes sense to me now. :) But what is going on in this section: $\frac{a(h)}{4-h} = \frac{a}{4} = \frac{1}{4} \Longrightarrow a(h) = \frac{1}{4}(4-h)$. For instance, why are we dividing $a(h)$ by $4 - h$ in $\frac{a(h)}{4-h}$? I realise that $4-h$ here is the remaining height and $a(h)$ is the base of the triangle in the image, but why are doing these specific calculations?

Comment: The sides $a$ and $4$ of the larger triangle respectively correspond to the sides $a(h)$ and $4-h$ of the smaller triangle, and the two triangles are simila, so by similarity the ratios $a/4$ and $a(h)/(4-h)$ are proportional (or equal to each other). That is just the nature of similarity

Comment: Wow, this makes sense! And it's such a clever solution! Thank you very much; this was very enlightening.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help